# Aligning data which contains strings

Tags: c++, output

I'm an online student for a C++ course. my intended output should look like so...

[intended output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrEuE.jpg)

Instead it looks like

[output program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrKpu.jpg)

my code fr this is as follows

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            outFile << left << setw(25)
                << studentList[i].studentLName + ", " + studentList[i].studentFName
                << right << " " << setw(6) << studentList[i].testScore
                << setw(6) << " " << studentList[i].grade << endl;
```

Yes, the data is all correct. But I cannot get a clear answer on how to align the testScore output in the exact same column spaces, because setw only begins when the student name strings end, which varies, and therefore makes the adjacent code uneven.

Comment: Compose a `std::string name = LName + ", " + FName`, and use `name.length()` to find the whitespace count in `outFile.write(" ", count)` ...

Comment: I tested this code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/tNFIle), and I see the output that you expect. I guess that the code you posted is different from the code you actually run.

Answer (score 0):

`setw` sets only the width of the next element you insert. Concatenate the last name, comma and the first name to a temp string, set the width and insert the temp string.